# Large WHERE query

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

What is the best way to query a database with a large set of up to 500 comparisons per row.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = x OR column = y OR column = z OR ...(x500)
```

I estimate that the table could grow to up to thousands of entries in the short term.
Thanks

Comment: Do you test on the same column each time?

Comment: there probably is a better way to do it, can you post the kind of data you will be selecting?

Comment: the comparisons will be longs, or more specifically facebook ids

Comment: @Mr47 yep same column every time

Comment: What is the source of all the values you are testing?  Is it data driven, or UI driven?

Comment: @The Evil Greebo; data from a client is being processed on a server to provide back the correct information. It would suck at the moment as a UI backend ;)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use it as one - just needed to know the source because it affects the answer.  If it were data driven, for instance, you'd be potentially looking at a join or a subquery situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `WHERE column IN(x,y,z...)`

Comment: Thanks for that should've read a bit more:) I just want something that works for now so i'll look into optimisations and design a bit later.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing a few... say less than 20 or so, you could use an IN (....) clause.  However, if you are doing something that will normally span 100's or 1000's on a regular basis, I would use a temp table of just "columnX" values and insert into that all the possible values... then query a join using this temp table as basis to the other...

```
select YT.*
   from
      JustValuesTable JVT
         Join YourTable YT
            ON JVT.ColumnX = YT.ColumnX
   rest of query...
```

Comment: good idea thanks mate:)there will also be comparisons on a few other columns so this looks good.

Comment: your way is a good idea, if the value in the where clause are different each time. otherwise, a view or a normal datatable would be ok. most databases have a upper limit of the statement size, and also a limit for the values in the in list.

Comment: the problem here is the set of all possible values is large, the amount of facebook acccounts style of large

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can use the in clause ..

`select * from table where column in ('asdf', 'aqwer' .....)`

additional, you may want to create a view, containing your allowed values, and then

```
select * from table where column in (select your_field_name from your_view)
```

Comment: In subselects are perfrormance killers (you can read why [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503671/need-help-with-optimizing-a-sql-query/6503698#6503698)

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using an `IN` query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (x, y, z)
```

That would make it a little more readable at least and I think should improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [IN function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)?